# Need some initial guidance for Android and iOS app using MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios

I'm about to start the development of an app where I'll need to make use of queries to retrieve information from a database and print it on my app. I have a lot of experience doing this using PHP/MySQL coding but I have never done it on a mobile app. How would you recommend I begin my coding? Are there any tips you can share to help me develop this app?

I also need to develop this app in both android and iOS. What should I be aware of when doing this? Is there any builder (other than Flash builder) to export both versions of my app?

Thanks, and any information helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you storing database locally or accessing remote database.

I am a IOS developer so I can give u tips about  IOS only. But concept must be similar to Android as well.

If you are storing database locally in the app, there is Sqlite and coredata for that. And different wrapper framework such as FMDB for sqlite makes things easy for this.

If you are accessing remote database you could do that with the help of APIS that consumes JSON/XML formatted data from the server database. Apple has provided inbuilt XML and JSON parser for this. But framework like AFNetworking could be really handy.